# Adding new files to a running hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

consider that you have 10GB data and you want to process them by a MapReduce program using Hadoop. Instead of copying all the 10GB at the beginning to HDFS and then running the program, I want to for example copy 1GB and start the work and gradually add the remaining 9GB during the time. I wonder if it is possible in Hadoop.

Thanks,
Morteza

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible with MapReduce.  When you initiate a MapReduce Job, part of the setup process is determining block locations of your input.  If the input is only partially there, the setup process will only work on those blocks and wont dynamically add inputs.

If you are looking for a stream processor, have a look at Apache Storm https://storm.apache.org/ or Apache Spark https://spark.apache.org/